# How to properly dequeue scripts and styles in child theme?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, scripts, wp-register-script

I made a parent theme and a child theme in one of my project. I enqueued CSS and JavaScripts in my parent theme like below:

```
function project_necessary_scripts() {
    //Stylesheets
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-map', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.css.map' );
    wp_register_style( 'project-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'project-css' );

    //JavaScripts
    wp_register_script( 'modernizr-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js', array(), '2.8.3' );
    wp_register_script( 'project-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/project.min.js', array('jquery'), '20150401', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'project-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_necessary_scripts' );
```

Now, in my **Child theme** I want to dequeue some stylesheets and javascripts. So I used the following code:

```
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'modernizr-js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'project-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

But actually the `bootstrap.css.map` file is still enqueuing, but the modernizr-js project-js is not loading, so it's working partially. How can I solve that?

I even tried action priorities:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts', 11 );
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are very nearer to the solution, because you are on the right path. Just to tweak a little bit:

There are two such action hooks:

1. [`wp_print_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts), and
2. [`wp_print_styles`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles)

So the way you can do it, is: hook 'em differently:

```
//Dequeue Styles
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles' );

//Dequeue JavaScripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'modernizr-js' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'modernizr-js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'project-js' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'project-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

And the correct way is to deregister them beside dequeuing. So first dequeue them, and then deregister them accordingly.

Comment: according to [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts): _Since WordPress 3.3, wp_print_scripts should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts. Use wp_enqueue_scripts instead._

Comment: @user1264304 We're not enqueueing things here, we're dequeueing things.

Comment: yes, but according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157531/how-can-i-remove-jquery-from-the-frontside-of-my-wordpress/27048128#27048128), one should use `add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts')`

Answer (score 5):

This is not the proper way. WordPress said not to use both wp_print_scripts, and
wp_print_styles since WordPress 3.3.

Either you are enqueueing or dequeueing, the proper way is:

```
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'modernizr-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts', 100 );
```

Don't forget to use the priority. Without priority, it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

For Dequeue Scripts, don't add the last "-js" or "-css" on ID part. I was using WordPress 5.8. It works for me.

ABOVE CODE:

```
//Dequeue JavaScripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'modernizr-js' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'modernizr-js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'project-js' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'project-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

WORKING CODE:

```
//Dequeue JavaScripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'modernizr' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'modernizr' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'project' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'project' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

Make sure to see the page source for script id first to remove the "-js" part. Remove last -js only.

For eg:
If your Script ID is project-js-js then remove last **-js** only and use project-js on dequeue action. Same for CSS as well remove last **"-css"** part.

Comment: This was key for me, been fighting with this for hours. Thanks.