# configuration for child theme

Tags: child-theme

I have some trouble to configure and setup my wordpress child theme.

I buy a themes and when I try to do a child. I think the child function is never trigged also, the override files not work too.

**Tree folder**:

[image: tree folder description here]

My theme is activated.

**style.CSS**:

```
/*
Theme Name:   Kidslife Child
Theme URI:    http://localhost/child/
Description:  Kidslife Child Theme
Author:       localhost
Author URI:   http://localhost
Template:     kidslife
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain:  kidslife-child
*/
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url("../kidslife/style.css");
```

I try to use this **function.php**:

[image: function.php]

but the `wp_die` is never triggered.

Also, in the **Tree folder**, I add the custom.js (in the same folder/name as the parent) and he is never loaded.

What I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file must be **functions.php** in plural form not function.php

Comment: true. functions.php works now. But the custom.js is never triggered

Comment: That because of you are calling **get_template_directory_uri()** instead of **get_stylesheet_directory_uri()**. Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: Try wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/public/custom.js', array(), '', true ); // Enqueue in footer, also empty short array initialization may cause errors.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I tried. it not work. it load the Parent and mine not appear. even if I put like: `wp_dequeue_script('custom-script');` before with an `add_action` with priority 5 or 70..

Comment: Use a different handler for your script. The dequeue may not work because of the child functions.php is loaded before the parent one. Also, the priority is inverse, minor number take precedence, so if you want to dequeue a script you should use a lower priority, try 20, 40, 50 I don't know which one the parent use.

Comment: the parent use the normal priority with:
`wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', IAMD_FW_URL.'js/public/custom.js',array(),false,true);` Well, I tried with 100 and both are loaded -_-"

Comment: gotcha!!! need to `deregister` after `dequeue` [See reference](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/189986/99064)