# My elementor is not opening in WordPress because of "cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js"

Tags: cloudflare

In my WordPress website, I am using the Cloudflare and Elementor editor also but when I am trying to edit the page using the Elementor, my Elementor is not opening. I think it is because of the Cloudflare in my WordPress.

Cloudflare has added the `script` in the head and also in the footer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/95c75768/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="9838dd25b616f37c8176faa3-|49"></script>
```

So, How to exclude the script from WordPress?

Added this in my **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

if ( 'script-handle' !== $handle )
    return $tag;

return str_replace( "type='text/javascript' src", ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag     );
}, 10, 2 );
```

> But not working.

Also tried this by adding in the **functions.php**:

```
<script data-cfasync=”false” src=”/javascript.js”></script>
```

> But not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This helps me to solve the problem:

https://snifflevalve.com/elementor-tutorials/elementor-cloudflares-rocket-loader-not-play-well-together/

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using a filter?
[wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) function would be much better.
Anyways, Rocket Loader seems to be conflicting with some WP component, i.e Jetpack.
Hope can help

Comment: Hi SHax, I want to dequeue the rocket loader script because it is creating a problem with the elementor editor. So, can you help me with that?

Comment: This is well explained here, please check: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189985/how-to-properly-dequeue-scripts-and-styles-in-child-theme

Comment: I think this is a script that Cloudflare is adding as it caches the site. I don't think it's a script you can dequeue from inside WordPress, because it's not added there.

Comment: if so, unique opportunity is 1) disable CF 2) change theme